# how to select from sqlite3.db where i compare a result of equation that has variables from the db?

Tags: python, sqlite

if i have a table like this:

```
("CREATE TABLE table (name text,x real, y real, state text) ")
[('name_1' ,x, y, 'active'), ('name_2' ,x, y, 'active')]
```

And two variable  `ref_1 = math.cos(some_input)`, `ref_2 = math.cos(some_input)`

and i want to `SELECT` only `state = 'active'` that their `math.cos(x) < ref_1`  and  `math.cos(y) < ref_2`

what can i add to this line: `curs.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE state = 'active #### code'` to endup with what i want. m not used to work a lot around databases

**This is the original line in my Code**
only lat and lon are variables inside the db

```
    active = 'active'
    curs.execute(f"SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE state = {active} and radius >= {math.sqrt( (lat - float(user_lat) )**2 + (lon - float(user_lon) )**2)} and min_radius =<  {-math.sqrt( (lat - float(user_lat) )**2 + (lon - float(user_lon) )**2)}  ")
```

i get this output:

```
     curs.execute(f"SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE state = {active} and radius >= {math.sqrt( (lat - float(user_lat) )**2 + (lon - float(user_lon) )**2)} and min_radius =<  {-math.sqrt( (lat - float(user_lat) )**2 + (lon - float(user_lon) )**2)}  ")
 NameError: name 'lat' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a f string to input different variables

```
curs.execute(f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE state = 'active and ref_1 < {math.cos(x)} code and ref_2 > {math.cos(y)}")
```

Comment: i patched the line but it doesnt work it still asks for x and y while i want to get from the db i re-edited the line to post the originale one

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3
import math
user_lat = #
user_lon = #
radius_length = #
state = 'active'

linktoauth = sqlite3.connect('DRIVERS.db')
curs = linktoauth.cursor()

def _radius_len(x, a, y, b):
    result =  math.sqrt((x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2)
    return result
linktoauth.create_function('rad', 4, _radius_len)
curs.execute(f"SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE state = ? and rad(lat, ?, lon, ?) <= ?  ",(state, user_lat, user_lon, radius_length,))
```